# PHP objects/classes

Tags: php

Hey,
I'm learning PHP, and i cant get my head around PHP classes/objects.
I understand JavaScript Objects/Classes, but i cant seem to grasp PHP.
What i mainly want it for is so i can do this sort of thing. (note this might cross JS and PHP)

```
$SQL = $db->query("SELECT *
                   FROM table
                   WHERE 1 = ");

$table_assoc = $db->assoc_array($SQL);
$table_array = $db->num_array($SQL);
```

Ive seen this type of thing done in PHP frameworks, but how does it all work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry, but the last sentence sounds like you should reread this part of the PHP manual first http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php and then come back with concrete implementation woes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to design a class for database access, I'd suggest you don't. There are already many classes that do just that. There is a PHP extension called PDO that can help you do the type of thing above and it is already well tested. Here is a link to good tutorial on it: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

OOP in PHP is very similar to OOP in other languages such as C++, C# (similar not the same, the basic concepts are very transferable. You should probably look into the links posted above to understand that in detail).

**Edit**

Let's see how this goes :). Here are the basics.

A `class` is a type of something. You can have a `Person` class, `Car` class etc.

An `object` is an `instance` of the `class`. It is one thing of that type. In a PHP context, this is how this will look:

```
class Person // Class
{
   public $name; // Property

   public function setName($n) // Method
   {
       $this->name = $n;
   }
}
```

I have created a class called Person.

```
$p = new Person(); // An instance of Person class
```

I have created an instance of the class. `$p` is an object of type `Person`.

The `$name` inside is a `member variable(/attribute)`. Think of it is as one of the properties that defines a `Person`. The `Person` class is a container for a set of data that defines a `Person`; `name` is one just one such data.

A class can have `methods`. Think of these as ways you interact with the class. You can call a method for the class to do something. In the above example, the `setName` method can be called with 1 argument. This argument is set as the value of the `name` member variable. The `$this` has to be used to refer to member variables (the `$n` is not a member variable, i.e. it is not a property of the class)

This should give you the basics to get started. Everything else builds on this.

Comment: ahh, i get it now, now i see how it's different from variables, so if i had $p = new Person(); and $x = new Person(); i could have 2 of the same class? with different properties for each?

Answer (score 2):

There some [excellent documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) on this topic -- I'd suggest taking a look at it.

Comment: ive tried reading it like 5 times, it's really confusing though.

Comment: Do you have any specific questions?  "Explain PHP classes to me" is a very vague question that nobody here is really interested in answering.  "I have trouble understanding getter and setter methods" or something like that would be much easier to answer.

Comment: i have trouble understanding any of it. ive never really learnt the names to everything, but i know it in my head as "that thing" and "that other thing" so the documentation just confuses me :/

Comment: If you don't understand any part of the documentation, there's not much we can do for you.

Comment: i 1/2 understand it, but not all of it. i've had to teach myself but i understand the core parts and their names

Answer (score 1):

Hope this can explain

```
$db = new db;
$SQL = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = ");


// The translate will be like this
// content of db class
class db {
    function query($query) {
        $return = mysql_query($query);
        return $return;
    }
}



// or without OOP it will be like this
function query($query) {
    $return = mysql_query($query);
    return $return;
}
// and we call it like this
$SQL = query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 = ");
```